# Priority Queue object comparator with hashset object

Tags: priority-queue, hashset, comparator

HashSet Object ct_set  City Object

how can i initialize a ProrityQueue object ct_pq with elements in ct_set with order from my populatation comparator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `PriorityQueue` with your `Comparator`, and then just call `addAll`:

```
HashSet<City> cities = ...;

PriorityQueue<City> queue = new PriorityQueue(new CityComparator());
queue.addAll(cities);
```

Note that if you've *really* got a `HashSet<Object>` instead (your question is far from clear) you should probably try to change your code so that you *do* have a `HashSet<City>` instead. Or you can always just cast each element:

```
HashSet<Object> cities = ...;
PriorityQueue<City> queue = new PriorityQueue(new CityComparator());
for (Object x : cities) {
    queue.add((City) x);
}
```